# Can't convert from <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision

Tags: r

Tried running this code and I am getting this error message:

"Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector. Can't convert from double to integer due to loss of precision." Could someone help either fix or convert so it recognizes the dataframe columns appropriately

```
data1 <- wins.df(data1, data1$q, wins.limits = c(.01, .99), append.wins.label = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
```

Here is the function:

```
wins.df <-
  function(X,
           var,
           wins.limits = c(.01, .99),
           append.wins.label = TRUE,
           verbose = TRUE) {
    Y <- X
    x <- X[, var]
    x.w <- wins(x, wins.limits)
    var.w <- var
    if (append.wins.label)
      var.w <- paste(var, ".w", sep = "")
    Y[, var.w] <- x.w
    if (verbose) {
      print(summary(Y[, var.w])) print(summary(X[, var]))
    }
    return(Y)
  }
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: what is ``wins.df``?

Comment: wins.df is a function that was created to winsorize the data

Comment: My best guess is that the function cannot convert from double to integer due to precision

Comment: Could you please provide `data1` -> `dput()`

Comment: This error can occur if you try to specify a non integer column in `dplyr`, for example `mtcars %>% select(1.1)`

Comment: Here is the function:                                                                                          
wins.df <- function(X, var, wins.limits = c(.01, .99), append.wins.label = TRUE, verbose = TRUE){
  Y <- X
  x <- X[, var]
  x.w <- wins(x, wins.limits)
  var.w <- var
  if(append.wins.label) var.w <- paste(var, ".w", sep="")
  Y[, var.w] <- x.w
  if(verbose){
    print(summary(Y[,var.w]))
    print(summary(X[,var]))
  }
  return(Y)
}

Comment: @DekeMarquardt The function includes another function called `wins`...what package are you using to winsorize? `wins` from `tsutils` (which takes a percentage or number of observations to winsorize)? Or something else? In addition, the second argument you are providing is `data1$q` - but in the `wins.df` function, it looks like you just want the column name from `data1` or just "q" (the name of the column of interest), not the numeric vector from the data frame.